# Separation of framework and to make it generic

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have designed a selenium framework taking the concept of POM(Page Object Model). I want to create a generic file of that framework keeping the required dll's so that it can be used by the manual testers within the team to automate other applications.

Comment: Hi Jeff. you got it right i have taken time to try to help myself but couldn't come to a proper conclusion, hence asked a question in SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can package the framework aspect as a NuGet package. The package can then be ingested by the other projects that require it.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package for how to create NUGet packages.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio for how to use NuGet packages.

Each test project can then include that NuGet package and implement it's own page object model classes for the specific application they are testing.

Comment: Thanks for the informative links. i went through the information provided in those links but for creating a package i need to update my VS to 2017 which won't be possible because my company provided default version of 2015. please suggest any alternative.

Comment: @Hargovind you shouldn't need to be on VS2017 to split your framework into a NuGet package, it should work fine for VS2015. Which bit are you seeing that is requiring you to upgrade?